# Chrome Browser Error: Attestation check for Topics on https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/ failed

Tags: html, google-chrome, attestations

In the latest Chrome version (Version 118.0.5993.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)), for a software product I'm selling, I'm getting:

Attestation check for Topics on https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/ failed.

on line 1 (the `<DOCTYPE html>` tag).

This appears in Dev Console. Google is providing no documentation that I can find on this on what to do. No links explain anything. Am I supposed to add some `META` tags in the HTML to explain my software product?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what I understand, if you set the header

```
Permissions-Policy: browsing-topics=()
```

in your responses it should disable the attestation check whilst disabling the topic api.

In an .htaccess file, one can add:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Permissions-Policy "browsing-topics=()"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am facing this issue on Shopify.. not sure how to do it there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For Nginx it works like this in your `server{}` block `add_header Permissions-Policy "browsing-topics=()" always;`

Comment: is this a meta tag that we should add?

Comment: @Sagive you need to read about the difference between HTTP headers and meta tags. HTTP headers are sent before HTML is even transmitted.

Answer (score 8):

The browser checks for the `browsing-topics` Permission-Policy and fails to find it because most websites have not implemented this experimental feature yet.

At the time of this writing (11. February 2024), the `browsing-policy` Permission-Policy is still an experimental feature.

Here's the MDN Web Docs documentation for this: [Permission-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy)

The Permission-Policy for `browsing-topics` currently links to an empty document that is likely to be updated once this feature becomes stable: [browsing-topics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy/browsing-topics)

Here's the up-to-date [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/) statistic on browser support for [Permission-Policy](https://caniuse.com/permissions-policy). (Currently at 71.54%)

To scan and check what security headers your website supports (or is missing), use: [securityheaders.com](https://securityheaders.com/)

To avoid the dev console error, set the Permission-Policy `header` like this (credit to [noboomu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77305183/4688612)):

```
Permissions-Policy: browsing-topics=()
```

For the `.htaccess` file (credit to [noboomu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77305183/4688612)).

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Permissions-Policy "browsing-topics=()"
</IfModule>
```

For nginx (credit to [ViaTech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77305183/4688612)):

```
server {
    ...
    add_header Permissions-Policy "browsing-topics=()" always;
    ...
}
```

For nodejs (credit to [ofir_aghai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698297/4688612)):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Permissions-Policy', 'browsing-topics=()');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for **nodejs + express**:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Permissions-Policy', 'browsing-topics=()');
    next();
});
```