# Double Requests sent only on Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, http

I tried to apply OAuth2.0 on my company's website.

And while testing our code on Google Chrome,
we found that there had been double requests sent to server.

The error messages we found from console were below.

[1] first message

```
attestation check for topics on https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/ failed.
```

[2] second message

```
Warning:componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. 
See ~~react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

Warning:Can't perform a React state on an unmounted component. This is no-op, but it indicates....
```

I searched similar issues, and saw link below.
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/224738467/chrome-duplicate-get-request?hl=en

It says that there could be

1. Network congestion or
2. Browser Caching issue,
3. Browser extension issue,
4. Server-side issue,

I checked 1)~4) and nothing seemed to cause the problem.

My co-worker found the link below

[Chrome Browser Error: Attestation check for Topics on https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/ failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77303375/chrome-browser-error-attestation-check-for-topics-on-https-pagead2-googlesynd)

It says the issue might be caused by recent Chrome Upgrade.
Did anybody also experience same issue?

or Anybody solve similar problem?

Please.. somebody help us..

PS. We tried another browser and no problem showed up there.